# Can mongodb $in operator take large number of values (approx 100K)?

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

In relational databases, it is not a good practice to have more values in the `IN` query. Can MongoDB support more values for $in aggregation operator?

If so can it work for more than 100K values on the indexed field and how is the performance? 
If not what are the alternate methods?

Comment: What did you find when you tested this?

Comment: You would probably be better served by actually describing the real problem you are trying to solve rather than asking if your "perceived" solution is actually workable. Bottom line is that even asking for 100K results from any query is not generally practical, let alone specifying each result via `$in`. If you describe the actual need then we can probably point out far better approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an index in field which you want to filter in $in operator you can put more than 100k values.
Its working fast for 500m collection))
How many documents you have in your collection?

Answer (score 0):

I would put just those values into a new collection, add an index, and then use a $lookup to join them.